# Location to redirect PHP

Tags: php, magento

```
<?php 
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$find = array(
    'equipamiento/impermeable-moto', 
    'equipamiento/ropa-termica-moto', 
    'equipamiento/ropa-accesorios',
    'equipamiento/protecciones',
    'equipamiento/electronica-moto',
    'equipamiento/mono-moto',
    'equipamiento/pantalon-moto',
    'equipamiento/botas-moto',
    'equipamiento/chaquetas-moto',
    'equipamiento/cascos-moto',
    'equipamiento/equipaje',
    'equipamiento/guantes-moto',
    'equipamiento',
    'recambios/accesorios',
    'recambios/lubricantes',
    'recambios/sistema-frenado-moto',
    'recambios/suspension',
    'recambios/baterias-moto',
    'recambios/baterias-moto',
    'recambios'
);
foreach ($find as $v) {
    if (stripos($url, $v) !== false) {
        Header( 'HTTPS/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        Header( 'Location: https://example.com/'.$v.'.html');
        exit;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to redirect 404 to /subcategory root with a foreach like this:

Example:

- If 404 is in subcategory domain.com/helmet/whatever, I try to send to domain.com/helmet (helmet is cascos in spanish)

**Everything is OK, but when I am trying to redirect when no words of my array is the URL to my homepage, I can't do it.**

Comment: Why do you not just add another relocation after the `foreach` loop? Like this, it would only be executed if no relocation occured inside the loop.

Comment: Can you clarify in which case the redirect does not happen and what you've tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is equipamiento/impermeable-moto a directory?

If so, you can't add .html to it even if you have an index page for the directory and you should change the header to:

```
header( 'Location: https://example.com/'.$v);
```

If it isn't a directory your example doesn't apply because domain.com/helmet/whatever is in the /helmet/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your a looking for a concrete URLs to redirect you can do this directly in the backend. Is the recommended way:

Magento 1
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/search_seo/seo-url-redirect-create.html

Magento 2
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html

On the other side, if you are looking to apply some logic as you told for subcategories maybe you could develop a module.

This module could have the next logic:

`If $URL == 404
then $priorURL = $URL - $URL_lastSlash
if $priorURL is category then redirect`

Regards.